# Add BCC to all emails in Magento

Tags: email, magento, transactional

As in the title, I need to have a copy of all emails through Magento to a specific email address.
In which file I've to work and how can I obtain the result?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

System > Configuration > Sales > Sales E-Mails. Navigate to each email type then `Send Order Email Copy To` and set the Method to BCC via `Send Order Email Copy Method`.

Or

```
 $mailTemplate->setTemplateSubject($mailSubject)->addBCC('youremail@add.ress')
 ->s‌​endTransactional($templateId, $sender, $email, $cus_name, $data, $storeId);
```

Comment: Thanks, for the second option: in which file?

Answer (score -1):

Unlike `addBcc`,`addCc` is not defined in class `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template`. You can either extend `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` class to include addCc method in a similar fashion as `addBcc`, or modify your code like this:

```
// Send Transactional Email
try{
  $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
  $mail->getMail()->addCc('abc@gmail.com');  

  $mail->addBcc('abcd2@gmail.com')
  ->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $recepientEmail, $recepientName, $vars, $storeId);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    print_r($e);
}
```